# php combine keys with values in associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm trying to manipulate an associative multidimensional array. I've extracted the keys from an array that I want to apply to another's values . . .

These are the keys that I've extracted in another function

```
$keys = array (
    "id" => "id",
    "addr_street_num" => "addr_street_num",
    "addr_street" => "addr_street",
    "price" => "price",
    "days" =>"days",
    "state" => Array
        (
            "id" => "id",
            "name" => "name"
        ),

    "city" => Array
        (
            "id" => "id",
            "web_id" => "web_id",
            "name" => "name"
        )
);
```

This array has the values I'd like to combine together

```
$vals = array (
    "0" => "830680",
    "1" => "20",
    "2" => "Sullivan Avenue",
    "3" => "333000",
    "4" => "12",
    "5" => Array
        (
             "0" => "4",
             "1" => "Maryland",
        ),

    "6" => Array
        (
            "0" => "782",
            "1" => "baltimore",
            "2" => "Baltimore",
        )
);
```

When I try to do array_combine($keys, $val);
I get 2 Notices about Array to string conversion

I guess array_combine only works on one dimensional arrays, any ideas on how to approach this?

If $keys was modified could it be combined with the values - problem is the shape of $keys is what I want to end up with?

Comment: the expected output is?

Comment: all the keys in the second array the same as the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done recursively.

```
function combine_recursive($keys, $values) {
    $result = array();
    $key = reset($keys);
    $value = reset($values);
    do {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result[key($keys)] = combine_recursive($key, $value);
        } else {
            $result[key($keys)] = $value;
        }
        $value = next($values);
    } while ($key = next($keys));
    return $result;
}
```

This works for me with your example arrays. I'm sure this will give you all kinds of weird results/errors if the array structures are different from each other at all.

Comment: This works great with the example, and I do expect the array structures to be identical.  Thanks for your help.